# Как сделать систему платной ежемесячной подписки на продукт?

Tags: javascript, php, api

Всем доброго времени суток!
Идея такая, на сервере будет лежать библиотека, которая добавляет подписавшимся пользователям некий функционал на сайт. Практически весь функционал написан на js. Очень важно чтобы пользователи не видели кода кроме того что я им предоставлю. Хочется сделать как facebook делает со встроенными комментариями, дая пользователям код для встраивания на страницу (html блок, и js с его айди и активной лицензией) Вот пример facebook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0&appId=&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
```

Ну либо что-то похожее. Пользователи будут сами добавлять этот код у себя на странице.
Как такое можно сделать? Какие технологии мне понадобятся?
Если что-то не понятно, то прошу задавать ваши вопросы в комментариях
P.S. Вот как выглядят комментарии фейсбука после вставки кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или хотябы подскажите как такое называется чтобы правильно погуглить)

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать не html а php страницу. проверять зарегистрирован пользователь или нет и в зависимости от этого показывать страницу